# Use block in Swift giving error "Variable used within its own initial value"

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, closures

This is my code in obj-c:

```
__block NSString *requestReference = [self operation:method url:url parameters:parameters headers:headers success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
NSError *error = [NSError errorWithSessionTask:task responseObject:responseObject];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error - %@", error);
    [delegate requestWithReference:requestReference didFinishWithBusinessError:error];
} else {
    id responseModel;
    if (modelClass && responseObject) {
        if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            // if response is a dictionary, create model out of it
            responseModel = [modelClass objectFromDictionary:responseObject error:&error];
        } else if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        }
    }
} } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
[delegate requestWithReference:requestReference didFailWithError:error]; }];
```

and this is the code after conversion in Swift:

```
var requestReference = self.operation(method, url: url, parameters: parameters, headers: headers, success: {(_ task: URLSessionDataTask, _ responseObject: Any) -> Void in
    var error = Error(sessionTask: task, responseObject: responseObject)
    if error {
        print("error - \(error)")
        delegate.request(with: requestReference, didFinishWithBusinessError: error)
    }
    else {
        var responseModel: Any!
        if modelClass && responseObject {
            if (responseObject is [AnyHashable: Any]) {
                // if response is a dictionary, create model out of it
                do {
                    responseModel = try modelClass.object(fromDictionary: responseObject)
                }
                catch {
                }
            }
            else if (responseObject is [Any]) {

            }
        }
    }
}, failure: {(_ task: URLSessionDataTask, _ error: Error) -> Void in
    delegate.request(with: requestReference, didFailWithError: error)
})
```

I have converted and come up with this code.
everything is working in this code
But I'm getting error:

> "Variable used within its own initial value"

Comment: You might want to include that the problem is `requestReference`, which is the variable being defined, but is also used both in the success and the failure block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Swift compiler is very strict and checks that every variable has
a defined value before it is used. The compiler
does not know that in your case, the closures will be executed only
*after* the `requestReference` variable is defined.

In such cases you can use an *implicitly unwrapped* optional:

```
var requestReference: String! 
requestReference = self.operation(..., success: {(_ task: URLSessionDataTask, _ responseObject: Any) -> Void in
    // ... 
    delegate.request(with: requestReference, didFinishWithBusinessError: error)
}, failure: {(_ task: URLSessionDataTask, _ error: Error) -> Void in
    delegate.request(with: requestReference, didFailWithError: error)
})
```

An implicitly unwrapped optional is a promise to the compiler:
The variable has no value *now,* but it will have a value when it is used.

Comment: "the compiler does not recognize that in your case, the closures will be executed only after the requestReference variable is defined." There is no guarantee of that. We only *assume*, based on the names of the parameters, that the functions are executed asynchronously, but technically it is perfectly legal for the method to execute them synchronously if it wants. Then compiler is right to not make such an assumption.

Comment: @newacct You are right. I have changed the wording. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Define it first, then use it:

```
var requestReference = ""
requestReference = self.operation...
```