# Variable used within its own initial value in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I try to write an animation with Swift 5, following are some codes

```
let animations:(() -> Void) = {
    self.keyboardOPT.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0,y: -deltaY)
    if duration > 0 {
        let options = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt((userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).intValue << 16))
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: options, animations: animations, completion: nil)
    } else {
        animations()
    }
}
```

But in `animations: animations` and `animations()` it shows error:

> Variable used within its own initial value

Comment: The name of your block constant is `animations` => `let animations:...`. Inside this block, in your `else` statement, you also call `animations()`. So your calling the block inside the block. You cannot do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use block in swift giving error "Variable used within its own initial value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285496/use-block-in-swift-giving-error-variable-used-within-its-own-initial-value)

Answer (score 1):

You can not call itself when initializing.
You can achieve it like this also.

```
var animations:(() -> Void)!

animations = {
    animations()
}
```